# Are we able to "combine" two analytic continuation to get another?

Tags: complex-analysis

Say, I want to find the analytic continuation of the function $f(z)$ defined on $D=\{a:-\pi/5<arg(a)<\pi/5\}$ to the slit plane $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$. I assume that $f(z)$ is real on the boundary of $D$ and has analytic continuation on $\bar D$. I can shift $f(z)$ to $f(ze^{-\pi/5})$ and do the Schwarz reflection principle. I can do this twice, shift it back, and restrict the domain to get the analytic continuation on the upper half plane. I can do the same thing on the lower half plane to get the analytic continuation on the lower half plane. But I don't know if I'm able to combine these two analytic continuations to get the analytic continuation on the whole slit plane. Can anybody give me any tips?..

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is analytic for $arg(z)\in (a,b),z\ne 0$ continuous on $arg(z) \in [a,b],z\ne 0$ and real on $arg(z)=b,z\ne 0$ then the Schwartz reflection along $arg(z)=b$ gives that $f$ extends analytically to $arg(z)\in (a,b+(b-a))$, and it is continuous on $arg(z)\in [a,b+(b-a)]$ and real on $arg(z)=2b-a$. So we can repeat and extend more and more the domain.

If $2b-2a>2\pi$ then $f(e^{2i\pi}z)$ doesn't have to be the same as $f(z)$, our analytic continuation may be "multi-valued" (try with $f(z)=z^{\pi},a=0,b=2$) that's the point of your branch cut on $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I've just read about "branch cut," and still not entirely sure about the concept, but basically we are cutting the continuation on $(-\infty,0]$ and changing the values on the lower half plane to make the function continuous, is it correct?

Comment: Try with $f(e^u)=e^{\pi u}$, it is analytic for $arg(z)\in (0,2\pi)$, then we can continue it analytically along any curve not passing through 0, and when doing a full rotation we obtain $f(e^{u+2i\pi})=e^{2i\pi^2} f(e^u)$. ie. $f(z)=z^\pi$ has a branch point at $z=0$, its analytic continuations are not all the same as itself. A branch cut is there to define a simply connected domain where the analytic continuation is unique, where the function is analytic.

Comment: How do we apply schwarz reflection principle if $2b-2a>\pi$? The theorem I have in mind is https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Notes/N24.pdf, and the setup doesn't make sense to me if the domain is more than a half plane

Comment: If you are completely lost then look at $F(u)=f(e^u)$. The sector becomes a strip.

Comment: Okay, I'll think about it, thank you so much

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I understand that by using Schwarz reflection lemma repeatedly, I can extend $a>>b$ to $a>>b+(b-a)$ to $a>>2b-a+(2b-2a)$ to $a>>4b-3a+(4b-4a)$ and so on. I imagine doing the reflection principle by shifting each cone to negative real axis and shifting it back, and the version of theorem I have in mind is math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Notes/N24.pdf. But what if, say, $2b-a+(2b-2a)-a>\pi$?

Comment: Then the domain we want to reflect on will "overfill" to the lower half plane. You said that we can choose  $2b-2a>2\pi$, but the problem arises when we want to extend the sector with angle more than $\pi$. Sorry if my argument misses the whole point

Comment: With $f$ your original function let $F(u)=f(e^u)$ for $\Im(u)\in (-\pi/5,\pi/5)$ and do the reflection along $\Im(u)=\pm \pi/5$ then again and again. You'll obtain an entire $4i\pi /5$ periodic function. It doesn't have to be $2i\pi$ periodic ie. $f(z)=F(\log z)$ doesn't have to be analytic on $\Bbb{C}^*$, but it is on $\Bbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: After thinking it over, I still have some doubts on my understanding. Can you please point out if this is correct? We apply schwarz reflection once along $b$, then we  get the analytic continuation from $(a,b)$ to $(a,2b-a)$. If this overfills complex plane, we use the "branch cut." In case $(a,2b-a)$ doesn't fill entire plane yet, we use the periodicity to extend until this fills out the entire plane and use the "branch cut."

Comment: I can see that we have the continuation on $(-\pi/5,3\pi/5)$. Then if we do the reflection principle again we get the continuation on $(-\pi/5,7\pi/5)$. I don't know how to apply it further, because now we have the domain $(0,8\pi/5)$ and this is more than half plane

Comment: I certainly understand that they are not $2\pi$ periodic though.